# Lazy Column/Row recomposition and perfomance

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have the following structure in the LazyColumn:

```
item {
  // complex layout with long time of recomposition and inside the HorizontalPager
}
items(list) {
  // item content
}
```

The issue is when I scroll down until the first item becomes invisible and scroll back, every time the first item appears on the screen it freezes.

I know that lazy layouts recompose their items unlike the RecyclerView which just binds data to a ViewHolder. But in this case the lazy layout works awful. Recomposing my first item takes too much time to provide a smooth scroll to the top.

Also I've mentioned in the structure that my complex layout is inside the HorizontalPager, which is a lazy layout too. Swiping this pager is not smooth either.

How to handle this? Is there a way to cache or prevent recomposition in a lazy layout? Something like RecyclerView binding?

Comment: Well, it seems like your complex item is not optimized well. Can you provide a code of that?

Comment: @Jakoss yeah, I know we can try to optimize the layout. But the question is not about that. What should we do if the complexity of the layout is not up to us? Like there is an AndroidView from a library that is a lot faster to use than developing your own implementation in Compose.

Comment: Well, i'm yet to find such complex layout. Compose is really good with complex, but there are some gotchas that will slow down even simple ones. So I think you're asking the wrong question. I'm positive that your issue might be solved by fixing the complex view or by some future update of compose (in this instance you can just stick with good old recyclerview)